# Is virus a concern running VMWare Fusion?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

Hi I have Macbook Pro running VMWare fusion, do I have to be concerned about viruses?
For example, if I have a trojan infected .exe key generator (legal for some reason), can I run it on the Mac without any problem?

Comment: +1 for not even trying to prove it's a legal keygen :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the virtual machine as a sandbox to execute programs that would make you nervous.  You are going to want to make sure that the guest is isolated from the host. If you are going to be executing malware and the like you probably do not want it using the network either.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's safe to run things in a Window Virtual Machine on the Mac.  The file system and application space are self contained.

Be careful not to share resources between the VM and the Mac.  You don't want the Windows machine to have access to the Mac's folders.

Of course, you can also run AntiVirus and Anti-Malware software inside of the VM.